# I am searching for a basic and simple NodeJS build tool for JS and SCSS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJS build tools such as Grunt, and have a very simple project with only JS and SCSS files. The structure is very simple:

```
js/
├─ main.js
├─ somefolder/
│  ├─ somefile1.js
│  └─ somefile2.js  
└─ vendor
   ├─ jquery.js
   └─ bootstrap.js 
scss/
├─ main.scss
├─ somefolder/
│  ├─ somefile1.scss
│  └─ somefile2.scss 
└─ vendor
   ├─ bootstrap/
   │  └─ bootstrap specific scss
   │     └─ ....
   │        └─ ....
   └─ bootstrap.scss
```

What I am searching for is a simple, fast and easy to use build tool which just compiles this into:

```
build/
├─ js/
│  └─ main.js
└─ css/
   └─ main.css
```

I'd also like that the JS and SCSS get concatenated in a certain order. Autocompile on filechange, e.g. when a file got uploaded per SFTP upload would be nice, but is not the most important feature.

So my question would be:

What would be the, for this purpose, best fitting and easiest to use build tool? I don't want to start any back and forth discussions on which one is the absolute best tool for everything on earth :D The reason for why I am asking this question is because I was looking at the Grunt documentation yesterday and it seemed pretty hard to learn to me, especially with the SCSS and ordered compile. I am also very busy with other projects, which mostly is the reason for why I am searching for a "easy" solution without having to mess around with e.g. Grunt a whole day to get it working. I know you people hate these beginner questions, but everyone starts at some time. So I please you to go easy on me.